# Updating access error

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, updating

```
    Dim conn As OleDbConnection
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand

    Public Sub openDB()
        conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\VFMS_DB.mdb;" & "Jet OLEDB:System Database=Security.mdw;User ID=Adster;Password=300624;")
        conn.Open()
    End Sub

    Public Function UpdateUser() As Integer
        Dim retCode As New Integer

        Try
            openDB()
            cmd = conn.CreateCommand()
```

The update command below keeps giving me this error: "Conversion from string "' WHERE [Username] = '" to type 'Double' is not valid."  and I don't know why. The aUserName field is a String field and I checked to make sure it's populated.

```
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Users SET [First Name] = '" & aName & "', [Last Name] = '" & aSurname & "', [Contact Number] = '" & aContactNum & "', [Password] = '" & aPassword & "', [User Rights] = '" & aUserRights + "' WHERE [Username] = '" + aUserName + "' "

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            conn.Close()

            'rsAddRecs = rsConn.Execute("UPDATE Users ([First Name], [Last Name], [Contact Number], [User Name], [Password], [User Rights]) VALUES ('" & aName & "','" & aSurname & "','" & aContactNum & "','" & aUserName & "','" & aPassword & "','" & aUserRights & "')")

            retCode = 0
            'rsConn.Close()
            Return retCode

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString, ex.Message, MessageBoxButtons.OK)
            retCode = 1
            Return retCode
        End Try
    End Function
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a typo. You're using **+** concat characters at the end of the sql string instead of **&** characters

**Wrong**

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Users SET [First Name] = '" & aName & _ 
                  "', [Last Name] = '" & aSurname & _
                  "', [Contact Number] = '" & aContactNum & _
                  "', [Password] = '" & aPassword & "', [User Rights] = '" & _
                  aUserRights + "' WHERE [Username] = '" + aUserName + "' "
'                             ^                          ^           ^
```

**Right**

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Users SET [First Name] = '" & aName & _
                  "', [Last Name] = '" & aSurname & _
                  "', [Contact Number] = '" & aContactNum & _
                  "', [Password] = '" & aPassword & "', [User Rights] = '" & _
                  aUserRights & "' WHERE [Username] = '" & aUserName & "' "
'                             ^                          ^           ^
```

Answer (score 0):

You SQL code uses `[Username]`:

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Users SET ... [Username]...
```

Whereas you commented out code used `[User Name]`:

```
'rsAddRecs = rsConn.Execute("UPDATE Users ... [User Name]...
```

Could the wrong column name be the source of the problem?

Another thought: have you sanitized your parameter values e.g. could the value contain a single quote that is upsetting the dynamic SQL. In any case, I think you should consider using prepared statements (or even PROCEDURES) and using Parameter objects to call the SQL, thereby deferring the sanitizing of the parameter values to the OLE DB provider, which will of course know more about the subject than you or I :)